# CSS collect similar properties?

Tags: css

How can I "collect" CSS statements? I have several th classes that I want to align the same like `table.t-data-grid thead tr th.*`

How can I collect eg the following?

```
table.t-data-grid thead tr th.depot, table.t-data-grid thead tr th.amount ... {

}
```

Comment: Do you want to target all th 's?

Comment: yes that's what I intended: all th's of depot or amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need that complex a selector? The less complex your selector is, the better is its performance. So just put in just as much as is necessary to target the correct elements.

It looks like, you would be better of with just

```
.t-data-grid .depot, .t-data-grid .amount { ... }
```

Comment: Good point, though there is sometimes the issue of specificity: when you drop components from a selector, it becomes less specific in the CSS cascade sense, and the rule may therefore get overridden by a rule with a more specific selector.

Comment: yes absolutely I need the previx `table.t-data-grid thead tr th.` because it is for styling a grid component of a JEE framework (tapestry5), thus I cannot decide to use less complexer selectors. So am I right that I cannot trim these expressions?

Comment: @membersound if you can't drop parts of the selector itself, you can't reduce the overall size here, I am afraid.